# 403- request has insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-authentication

I want to link and view the analytics account linked with Google Adwords.

Procedure used:

1. Authenticating google account with scopes "Ananlytics and Adwords" with following url
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics
2. After getting the authentication response creating Google analytics service object.
3. Google ads link API throwing error "Insufficient Premissions" screenshot attached

**Script :**

```
<?php

//function to authenticate google account and create analytics service object
function googleAuth(){

        if (!empty($code)) {

                        $postFields = 'client_id=' . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID') . '&client_secret=' . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET') . '&code=' . $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI');

                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);

                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

                        $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);

                        if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
                                return $Rec_Data;
                        }

                        $Rec_Data = json_decode($Rec_Data, true);

                        if (isset($Rec_Data['refresh_token'])) {
                                
                                try {

                                        $credentials = array('client_id' => Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID'), 'client_secret' => Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'), 'redirect_uris' => array(Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI')));

                                        $client = new \Google_Client($credentials);
                                                
                                                $client->addScope(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
                                                $client->setAccessToken($Rec_Data['access_token']);

                                                // Create an authorized analytics service object.
                                                $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

                                        


                                } catch (Exception $e) {
                                        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                                        die();
                                        
                                }

                        }
                } else {
                        if (!empty($id)) {
                                header("Location:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID') . "&redirect_uri=" . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI') . "&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state=" . $id . "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics");
                                exit;
                        }
                }
}

//function to fetch linked account list
function adwordsLinkAnalytics($analyticsAuth) {
                $this->autoRender = false;

        
                try {
                        $adWordsLinks = $analyticsAuth->management_webPropertyAdWordsLinks
                                ->listManagementwebPropertyAdWordsLinks('123456', 'UA-123456-1');

                } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
                        print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
                        . $e->getCode() . ':+' . $e->getMessage();
                        exit;

                } catch (apiException $e) {
                        print 'There was a general API error '
                        . $e->getCode() . ':-' . $e->getMessage();
                        exit;
                }
                pr($adWordsLinks);
                exit;
                
}
```

**Required result**: List of the analytics account linked with adwords account.

[image]

Comment: There is no `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords` scope. Check again on [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) page.

Comment: Please always include details of error messages as text, not images. Not only do images make it hard for anyone with visual impairments or a small screen to help you, they mean that nobody searching for that same error message will see your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing scope to management entities in Google Analytics, please look at this https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#analytics

**Please update your scope with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit"**

*My suggested Updates:*

```
function googleAuth(){

        if (!empty($code)) {

                --------------
                ---- Your existing script ----
                --------------
        
        } else {
                if (!empty($id)) {
                        header("Location:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=" . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID') . "&redirect_uri=" . Configure::read('GOOGLE_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI') . "&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&state=" . $id . "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit");
                        exit;
                }
        }
}
```

**Reference Url:** https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#analytics

[image]